# How to delete all rows from all tables belonging to a particular schema in a SQL Server 2012 database?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I want to delete all rows from all tables belonging to a particular schema in a SQL Server 2012 database.

I have a problem when trying to Delete data from all tables in a schema, what am I doing wrong here?

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DISABLE TRIGGER ALL ON ?'
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable @command1='Truncate Table ?',@whereand='and Schema_Id=Schema_id(''info'')'
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ENABLE TRIGGER ALL ON ?'
GO
```

I was getting error

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1 The ALTER TABLE statement
>   conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK__PayElemen__RealY__25476A76". The conflict occurred in database
>   "Saina", table "info.iYear", column 'Year'.

Could somebody help me with this please?

Comment: I think you have to remove first the foreign key. Like if you are trying to delete a table with a primary key that is a foreign key for the other table you will get an error because the foreign key is relying to that primary key. Just a guess though. Might help

Comment: So, if you have a table outside of the `info` schema that has a foreign key reference to a table within the `info` schema, what's meant to happen when the foreign keys are re-enabled? I suspect that's the nature of the FK that's failing in the error you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can I disable all Forreign Key Constraint?

Comment: You're already disabling all of the foreign keys. As I said, I believe the error is happening when you re-enable them afterwards.

Comment: thanks for your comment but I Can't disable all foreign keys. Could you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You can have a look at this [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3218/truncate-all-tables-in-a-sql-server-database/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to drop the constraints. or, use `DELETE FROM`

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DISABLE TRIGGER ALL ON ?'
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable @command1='Delete ?',@whereand='and Schema_Id=Schema_id(''info'')'
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ENABLE TRIGGER ALL ON ?'
GO
```